# Is there any useful links for option pricing (american + asian + european) using R

Tags: option-pricing, programming, american-options, european-options, asian-option

I'm trying to evaluate option pricing mainly american, asian and european options in order to get a plot to measure option valuation in time.
Is there any useful references to do that using R ?

Answer (score 4):

Below is an example of how you could plot a "call" option value with [RQuantLib](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RQuantLib/index.html):

```
library(RQuantLib)
library(ggplot2)
call_price <- sapply(seq(365,0,-1), function(x) AmericanOption("call", 100, 100, 0.2, 0.03, x/365, 0.4)$value)
qplot(day, call_price, data=data.frame(day=0:365, call_price=call_price), geom="line")
```

The code output:

[image]

Another useful package is [fOptions](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fOptions/)

There is also a book ["Option Pricing and Estimation of Financial Models with R"](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470745843,subjectCd-BA04.html)

Comment: Quite an improvement!

Comment: @BobJansen I have to work hard to improve my reputation :-)